# Does Microsoft Graph APIs support batch request

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Does graph apis: http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs
support batch get/post requests ?

Answer (score 1):

JSON batching is now available in the beta endpoint.  Docs are at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching.

We also have batching samples in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

[image: graph explorer batching samples]

Comment: Are there any more examples about how to do this with a C# console application? Specifically to batch add calendar events?

Comment: @Dan Thank you so much, The documentation page didn't cover what I needed, but the Combine a POST and a GET sample there did... I couldn't get the syntax correct for a POST request and that's just saved me! :) Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, it is part of our roadmap and we hope to enable it soon.

Comment: Any progress with batch support?

Comment: Yes, now Microsoft Graph supports JSON Batch in the v1.0 version.

Comment: Last time I looked the batch feature was limited and there was not many examples.